# Compare two arrays of objects and add a new attribute to the object that is matched

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays of objects like this:

```
let data1 = [ { userid_b: 'dan12345' }, { userid_b: 'emma12345' } ]
let data2 =[ 
  { username: 'dan', userid: 'dan12345' },
  { username: 'johndoe', userid: 'john12345' },
  { username: 'emma', userid: 'emma12345' },
  { username: 'Bob', userid: 'bob12345' },
  { username: 'Sam', userid: 'sam12345' } 
]
```

I want to compare these two of `userid_b` and `userid`, and if they are same, I want to add a new attribute to `data2`.

So I want the result like this:

```
let data2 =[ 
  { username: 'dan', userid: 'dan12345', newAttribute: true },
  { username: 'johndoe', userid: 'john12345' },
  { username: 'emma', userid: 'emma12345', newAttribute: true },
  { username: 'Bob', userid: 'bob12345' },
  { username: 'Sam', userid: 'sam12345' } 
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop both arrays and compare the values, making the assignment if necessary:

```js
var data1 = [
  { userid_b: 'dan12345' },
  { userid_b: 'emma12345' }
];

var data2 = [ 
  { username: 'dan', userid: 'dan12345' },
  { username: 'johndoe', userid: 'john12345' },
  { username: 'emma', userid: 'emma12345' },
  { username: 'Bob', userid: 'bob12345' },
  { username: 'Sam', userid: 'sam12345' } 
];

// Loop the main array
for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
  // Loop the second array
  for (var j = 0; j < data1.length; j++) {
    // If the user id matches
    if (data2[i].userid == data1[j].userid_b) {
      // Add the attribute
      data2[i].newAttribute = true;
      // Break out of the the 'j' loop to stop unnecessary iterations
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(data2);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be more efficient to loop over `data` first?

Comment: Yeah you might be right there. In any case you made me remember to add a of break in.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `data1` to a `new Map()`, and then iterate `data2`, whenever the `userid` is in the map add `newAttribute` prop to the object:

```js
const data1 = [ { userid_b: 'dan12345' }, { userid_b: 'emma12345' } ]
const data2 =[ 
  { username: 'dan', userid: 'dan12345' },
  { username: 'johndoe', userid: 'john12345' },
  { username: 'emma', userid: 'emma12345' },
  { username: 'Bob', userid: 'bob12345' },
  { username: 'Sam', userid: 'sam12345' } 
];

const usersSet = new Set(data1.map((item) => item.userid_b));

data2.forEach((item) => usersSet.has(item.userid) && (item.newAttribute = true));

console.log(data2);
```

Comment: Why are you using `Map` instead of `Set`?

Comment: I'm used to making object maps, so I naturally go for Map, but you're right, Set would be better in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do traverse over array using foreach loop see below

```
var data1 = [ { userid_b: 'dan12345' }, { userid_b: 'emma12345' } ];
    var data2 =[ 
      { username: 'dan', userid: 'dan12345' },
      { username: 'johndoe', userid: 'john12345' },
      { username: 'emma', userid: 'emma12345' },
      { username: 'Bob', userid: 'bob12345' },
      { username: 'Sam', userid: 'sam12345' } 
    ];

    data1.forEach(function(data1record,index,data1arr){

          data2.forEach(function(data2record,data2idx,data2arr){

                if(data1record.userid_b===data2record.userid){

                    data2record["newAttribute"]=true;
                }

          })
    });

    console.log(data2);
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt understood can you explain in detail?

Comment: datarecord2 is object which was in data2 array that having userid property so only i refered.In question was asking compare based on userid..

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make an array of new users for easy lookup.
const newUsers = data1.map(elt => elt.userid_b);

// Filter data2 down to only matching elements, then add new attribute.
data2.filter(elt => newUsers.contains(elt.username))
  .forEach(elt => elt.newAttribute = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this.

```js
let data1 = [{
  userid_b: 'dan12345'
}, {
  userid_b: 'emma12345'
}]
let data2 = [{
  username: 'dan',
  userid: 'dan12345'
}, {
  username: 'johndoe',
  userid: 'john12345'
}, {
  username: 'emma',
  userid: 'emma12345'
}, {
  username: 'Bob',
  userid: 'bob12345'
}, {
  username: 'Sam',
  userid: 'sam12345'
}];


var userIds = data1.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.userid_b;
});


var result = data2.map(function(dataObj) {

  if (userIds.includes(dataObj.userid)) {
    dataObj.newAttribute = true;
  }
  return dataObj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With  [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Take the usernames (values) from the objects of the first array:

```
var data1_values = data1.map(o => {
    return o.userid_b;
});
```

The result is `data1_values = ['dan12345', 'emma12345']`.

Now, go through the objects of `data2` with `map()`. Check with

```
data1_values.indexOf(o.userid) > -1
```

(`o` is an object of `data2`)

if `data1_values` has `o.userid` in it.

**In total:**

```js
let data1 = [
  { userid_b: 'dan12345' },
  { userid_b: 'emma12345' }
];
let data2 = [
  { username: 'dan', userid: 'dan12345' },
  { username: 'johndoe', userid: 'john12345' },
  { username: 'emma', userid: 'emma12345' },
  { username: 'Bob', userid: 'bob12345' },
  { username: 'Sam', userid: 'sam12345' }
];

var data1_values = data1.map(o => {
  return o.userid_b;
});

data2.map((o, i) => {
  if(data1_values.indexOf(o.userid) > -1) {
    data2[i]["newAttribute"] = true;
  }
});

console.log(data2);
```